# Possible to use AngularJS for a Chrome extension's options page?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, angularjs

For my Chrome Extension's options page, I'd like to use Angular.js (just for the options page, not for the extension's background JS or content scripts), but including it in my page and doing something like:

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app>
<head>
  <title>Shortkeys Options</title>
  <script src="../js/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="../js/angular.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="../js/options.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/options.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div ng-controller="OptionsCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="key in keys"></table>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

...throws this error in the dev tools console and nothing runs:

```
Error: Code generation from strings disallowed for this context
```

I assume it's because Angular is trying to write  tags to the page or assign inline event handlers or something that runs inline JS, which [is not allowed in Chrome extensions](https://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy.html#H3-1), so is there any way around this? Can I tell Angular to avoid using inline JS somehow, for example?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use `manifest_version: 2` by specifying that angular run in CSP-compliant mode. Just add the `ng-csp` attribute to the `<html>` in your panel page.

So your HTML would be like this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-csp ng-app>
<head>
  <title>Shortkeys Options</title>
  <script src="../js/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="../js/angular.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="../js/options.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/options.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div ng-controller="OptionsCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="key in keys"></table>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: how would this work in a Chrome Packaged app? I read it is not allowed