# Use AngularJS in a Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, angularjs

I want to use AngularJS in a Chrome extension but I have an error like this:

```
Error: SECURITY_ERR: DOM Exception 18
Error: An attempt was made to break through the security policy of the user agent.
    at new listConnection
```

**manifest.json :**

```
 {
  "name": "Chrome auditor connection",
  "version": "1",
  "icons": { "48": "icone.png",
            "128": "icone.png" },
  "description": "Chrome-auditor-connection is an extension for Google Chrome browser. It ensures that nobody connects to your browser with your profile.",
  "background": {
    "scripts": [
      "chrome_ex_oauthsimple.js",
      "chrome_ex_oauth.js",
      "background.js"
    ]
  },
  "browser_action": {
    "default_title": "Chrome auditor connection",
    "default_icon": "icone.png",
    "default_popup": "index.html"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "storage"
  ],
  "web_accessible_resources": ["index.html"],
  "sandbox": {
     "pages": ["index.html","index.js","angular.min.js"]
  },
  "manifest_version": 2
}
```

**index.js :**

```
function listConnection( $scope) {      
    $scope.connections = JSON.parse(localStorage['connectionHistory']);
}
```

I think the JSON.parse() is blocked by the Chrome "Content Security Policy" (CSP).

Do you have any solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your index.js is sandboxed as defined in your manifest.json file.
"A [sandboxed](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest.html#sandbox) page will not have access to extension or app APIs"
So it can't access localstorage.
Remove the sandbox or use something like https://github.com/jamesmortensen/chrome-sandbox-storageAPI for sandboxed pages.

Comment: `Local-storage` is not an extension or app API, it has its own `local-storage`,BTW how does the link help ?

Comment: @Sudarshan - The Chrome Sandbox StorageAPI is a library that uses postMessage to pass Chrome Storage data from a non-sandboxed wrapper to a sandboxed iframe, which can neither use localStorage nor Chrome Storage.  Alexander suggests storageAPI because it provides an abstraction that allows one to replace window.localStorage, without having to rewrite code, when porting a web page to a sandboxed iframe. However, I'm not sure it will work with the array notation, since I didn't design it with that in mind. So the asker would need to instead use the `getItem` method. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 4):

There are two answers for you:

1. Add `ng-csp` to your `<html>` tag, like this `<html ng-csp ng-app="AngularAppName">` . See this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11108679/possible-to-use-angularjs-for-a-chrome-extensions-options-page)
2. Add this line to `manifest.json` file

`"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'; object-src 'self' "`

Answer (score 0):

## Problems in your code

These are some of problems i see so far with code shared!.

- Your `index.html` is being used as `default_popup`, `web_accessible_resources` and in `sandbox Pages` . It is functionally incorrect, what is you want to develop?
- Why do you want to put `angular.min.js` in sandbox location?
- Is `index.js` used by `index.html`, if so there is no need to list it explicitly.
- Storage is an object per domain, your `localstorage` differs from sandbox and other pages.